# How do I get the Android Icons in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm using Android Studio, and I always see people's drawable calls to things like ic_launcher. I don't have any of these files - hell, where are they even stored? All of my few files begin with abc_ic. How would I go about getting the icons, and where would I put them?

Comment: You are asking how you can get a reference to the system icons that exist on the Android filesystem?

Comment: Yes, more or less exactly that. There's a whole bunch of system included comments that I can't find :d

Comment: ic_launcher is usually the icon of your app. look in the mipmap folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abc_` are `ActionBarCompat` stuff. It's used by ActionBarCompat. For instance, you'll find the overflow icon there (the vertical dots indicating the menu).

Then there is `android:drawable/` that contains the system stuff, not always convenient because it varies a lot from a version to another.

Finally, there is https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/ Pretty much all icons ever mentioned in material design are there, in black and white, in all sort of size, and for all densities.

Comment: Thanks so much! Both of those are what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the system's drawables by

`android:drawable/the_drawable_here` on XML and

```
getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.one_random_drawable,null);
```

programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The Android asset studio is a great tool for things like this. It will generate icons for all the main DPIs. It can be found here:
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

Comment: Thanks! But I'm looking for where I can find the vanilla icons.